# Terraform provisioned Private AKS cluster unable to deploy application from Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqaQc.png)

We are trying to deploy application to the provisioned private aks cluster using terraform in Azure devops, when we try to deploy helm or access the cluster we are getting error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvceb.jpg)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of errors. Post the text. In addition, please include **what you've tried** to solve the issue here. The error messages are pretty clear about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provided much information, i will do my best to help you:

It seems that the user or Service principal that is running the pipeline has permissions on subscription level to create the AKS but not enough permissions to create anything inside Kubernetes.

You can leverage RBAC, Azure AD & Azure RBAC with your Kubernetes. With Terraform you can specify `admin_group_object_ids` inside the `azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control` block. Just assign the group there and add the pipeline User / SP to that group.

Alternative you can use Azure build-in roles like `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role` and add your User / SP there.